# Как вытащить данные из цикла внутри SELECT

Tags: php, html

Есть таблица в MySQL под названием `doctors`.
Таблица состоит из `uid` (уникальный идентификатор доктора) и `fio` (ФИО). В выпадающем списке (в теге `SELECT`) вывожу ФИО всех врачей, которые есть в таблице `doctors` вот таким вот образом:

```
<select name="doctor" id="basic" class="selectpicker show-tick form-control" data-live-search="true" >
    <?php require ('includes/connection.php') ; ?> <?php  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM doctors ") 
            or die(mysqli_error());         
             ?> 
      <optgroup>
       <?php    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result )) {
            ?>
            <option value=""><?php
              echo (" ".$row["fio"]." ");
               $uidk =   $row["uid"];?></option>
       <?php }; ?>
      </optgroup>
    </select><input type="hidden" name="uid" id="uid" value="<?php echo $uidk ; ?>">
```

Используя переменную `$uidk`, пытаюсь передать скрытому полю под названием `uid`, UID (уникальный идентификатор) доктора, но проблема в том, что скрытое поле принимает только последнее значение, которое есть в таблице `doctors`. Как можно передать значение `uid` в скрытое поле в зависимости от выбранного в `select` значения?
Или какие ещё есть идеи?

P.S.
Пробовал передать через JS, используя код:

```
onchange="document.getElementById('uid').value =value ; "
```

Но он тогда брал последние два параметра из базы.

Comment: Тут `<option value="">` вместо пустого значения номер врача не пробовали передавать? :)

Comment: Фу, не используется шаблонизатор

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К чему эти сложности? Почему вы не можете просто дать имя селекту `uid` и в option values подставлять эти значения, Вот так:

```
<select name="uid" id="basic" class="selectpicker show-tick form-control" data-live-search="true" >
<?php require ('includes/connection.php') ; ?> <?php  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM doctors ") 
        or die(mysqli_error());         
         ?> 
  <optgroup>
   <?php    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result )) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row["uid"]; ?>"><?php
          echo (" ".$row["fio"]." ");
           $uidk =   $row["uid"];?></option>
   <?php }; ?>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

И при выборе у вас в `uid` будет id врача.

Comment: Visman, Yaroslav Molchan До этого делал так как Вы и написали но на странице в выпадающем списке у меня почему то отображается только номера а точнее UID врачей а не ФИО ...

Comment: Спасибо Вам обоим всё заработало так как надо ) и действительно почему я так усложнял себе жизнь )